# I need help creating an endpoint that can receive json data

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl, file-get-contents

I have created a php file that sends json data to an external url. Their API requires that I have a page on my website that receives the json responses for processing. The one that sends json data works well. I need help with the second php page that should process it

```
        $Url="http://example.com/submit.php";
        $date = date_create();
        $UserID=7;
        $Password='';//<-password written here
        $Timestamp=date_timestamp_get($date);
        $token=$UserID.$Password.$Timestamp;
        $data_string = array();
        $data_string = array(
        "AuthDetails" => array(
            array(
                "UserID" => $UserID,
                "Token" => md5($token),                 
                "Timestamp"=>$Timestamp
                )
            ),
        "MessageType"=> array(              
                "3"                     
            ),
        "BatchType"=>array(             
                "0"                     
            ),
        "SourceAddr"=>array(                
             "Example"                  
            ),
        "MessagePayload"=> array(
            array(
                "Text" => "Sample text message by Example :)"
                )
            ),
        "DestinationAddr" => array(
            array(
                'MSISDN'=>'254701000000',
                'LinkID'=>''
                )
            ),
        "DeliveryRequest" => array(
            array(
                'EndPoint'=>'',//<-URL that receives the response
                'Correlator'=>md5(uniqid())
                )
            )
        );
        $data_string=json_encode($data_string);
        $ch = curl_init();       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);          
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            )                                                                       
        );   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
            if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
```

Comment: What help do you need. There has to be a question in your question. So ask a question. You are new so welcome: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Oh and just in case you were confused, SO **is not a free coding service**

Comment: Hi, My question is, How do I write the script that receives the json data response?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is going to be a bit generic but it should put you on the right path.

So you have to write a script that will process the response from them i.e. your end-point for this circle of events.

So lets call it `my-enpoint.php`

So in the message you send to them you put the address of this new script into this parameter

```
"DeliveryRequest" => array(
        array(
            'EndPoint'=>'http://www.example.com/my-endpoint.php',
            'Correlator'=>md5(uniqid())
```

Now your script `my-endpoint.php` I am assuming they have said how they will return their reply, probably as POST variable. You process their reply basically like you would a submitted form from your own site.

So for example if their reply is POSTed

```
<?php

    // initial testing to see what comes back from them
    // as this wont be associated with a browser
    // dump their reply to a file so you can see whats there

    file_put_contents('reply.txt', print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

With the info you have provided this is about a much as I can do.

Comment: would it be more helpful if I mentioned that I am using codeigniter framework?

Comment: YES. But that does not actually change much, you just do the above in a codeigniter way.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, how do I do that?

Comment: I would build a controller just for this purpose.